# Equivalence of a Vector Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, vector-analysis

I have this for my homework and i need help with this question:
For a 2D vector, is norm2 > norm1 possible?
Characterize all 2D vectors for which the norm2 is equal to the norm1. Explain
graphically.

Comment: What is "norm2" and "norm1"? Do you mean $\ell^2$ norm and $\ell^1$ norm?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Answer (score 0):

For $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ we have

$$||(x,y)||_1 =|x|+|y| \ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=||(x,y)||_2,$$

since

$(|x|+|y|)^2=x^2+2|x||y|+y^2 \ge x^2+y^2$.

We have the equality

$$||(x,y)||_1 =|x|+|y| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=||(x,y)||_2$$

$ \iff$

$(|x|+|y|)^2=x^2+2|x||y|+y^2 = x^2+y^2  \iff xy=0$.